# Mock statsd client in Go test package

Tags: go, interface, mocking, statsd

I use [this](https://github.com/cactus/go-statsd-client) `statsd package` to send metrics to our `statsd server`. To initialize the client, I call a `metrics.Setup()` in my main which does the init. This package looks like this:

**package:**

```
package metrics

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/cactus/go-statsd-client/statsd"
)

// Client can be used to send stats to
var Client StatsdAccess

// Setup initialises metrics gathering
func Setup() {
    if Client == nil {
        prefix := fmt.Sprintf("app.%s", logging.GetHost())
        std, err := statsd.NewBufferedClient(fmt.Sprintf("localhost:1234", prefix, 0, 0)
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Errorf("unable to dial the statsd host: %q", err)
            return
        }
        Client = std
    }
}

// StatsdAccess is used as interface to statsd functions
type StatsdAccess interface {
    Inc(stat string, value int64, rate float32) error
    Gauge(stat string, value int64, rate float32) error
    Timing(stat string, delta int64, rate float32) error
}
```

From this moment on, the other package send metrics though this global Client by doing this: `metrics.Client.Inc("some.counter", 1, 1.0)`. This works fine, but now I have a problem with my test files. They now fail when a package actually uses the `metrics package` to send metrics. This is obvious, because the metrics package has not been initialized, etc. So my question -I think- is: how can I mock the `statsd client` in my test files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the project I work on use statsd and have teetered between just leaving the calls in the tests, because they are so lightweight, and programming to a metrics interface (as you have already done `StasdAccess`).

Since the interface is already initialized, you should be able to use the interface to break the configuration dependency in your code, and provide a [test implementation](https://about.sourcegraph.com/go/advanced-testing-in-go/#testing-as-a-public-api) to use in your tests:

```
package_metrics/
   testing.go
```

---

```
// testing.go

type StubStatsd struct {}
func (s StubStatsd) Inc(stat string, value int64, rate float32) error {
  return nil
}
func (s StubStatsd) Gauge(...
func (s StubStatsd) Timing(...
```

Now when your tests would like to call a method or initialize a component that requires a `StatsdAccess` parameter it could use the testing stub to meet the requirements

```
func TestSomething_NeedsStatsd(t *testing.T) {
     statsdStub := StubStatsd{}
     someMethodThatRequiresStatsd(stasdStub)
}
```